# adding matrices to n dimensional array with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Perhaps a simple questions, but I am using numpy, and iteratively generating 9x9x9 matrices.

I would like to stack these so I end up with Nx9x9x9, but using append, stack and stack it seems to vectorise one of the dimensions rather than add these as individual objects. any ideas how I can do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be resolved using `np.vstack` but to get this in the shape you want to need to add another dimension (an empty one) as first. Otherwise you would stack you current first dimension:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((1,2,2,2))
print(a.shape) # (1, 2, 2, 2)
```

or if you create your arrays, then add another dimension by:

```
a = np.ones((2,2,2))
a = a[None, :]  # Adds an dimension as first
```

and then to stack them you could use:

```
b = np.vstack([a,a])
print(b.shape) # (2, 2, 2, 2)
c = np.vstack([b,a])
print(c.shape) # (3, 2, 2, 2)
c.shape
```

you said you create them iterativly but if you only need the final result at the end you don't even need to use `vstack` just create a new array:

```
a = np.ones((9,9,9))
b = np.ones((9,9,9))
c = np.ones((9,9,9))
d = np.ones((9,9,9))
res = np.array([a, b, c, d])
print(res.shape) # (4, 9, 9, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)  I didn't know how to add an extra dimension to my 3 dimensional matrix! Very helpful

Comment: @i-am-spartacus You're welcome! If this really solves your problem it would be nice if you upvote or accept the answer. :)

Comment: `np.array([a,b,c,d])` should produce the same thing.  `np.vstack([i[None,...] for i in [a,b,c,d]])` is another expression.

Comment: @hpaulj - Yes, at first I thought of it and then forgot about it because he mentioned creating them iteratively and I wasn't quite certain what he meant. Thanks for the comment, I'll edit it.